# Centralizing vertically and horizontally with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three elements arranged in a row. The left most is a button, then there's some images in id="slide" and then I have another div. The html looks like:

```
        <div id="display">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1">
                    <div id="drawMenu" class="center-block">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" id="erase">Erase</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div id="slide">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div id="colorPicker" class="center-block">
                        <div class="color" id="white"></div>
                        <div class="color" id="yellow"></div>
                        <div class="color" id="green"></div>
                        <div class="color" id="blue"></div>
                        <div class="color" id="red"></div>
                        <div class="color" id="black"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The issue is, I have the images in the center but I can't get the two elements on each side to be centralized vertically and horizontally. The CSS looks like:

```
.color{
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
    margin: 2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#drawmenu{
    text-align: center;
}
.center-block {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

The only thing I believe is actually working is the text-align: center

Hopefully the image will explain what I'm looking for. Sorry about the quality. As good as I could get with paint. The grey parts on the sides are offsets.

http://i1028.photobucket.com/albums/y349/oqrgyikf/stackoverflow_zpsf3b6fa31.png

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

add a class to those columns so you can target them more efficiently, and then the following CSS:

```
.row{display:block;}
.vertimid{display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle ; height:auto; min-height:100%;}
.vertimid img{width:100%; height:auto;}
```

[See Bootply here](http://www.bootply.com/QriiCySI2t)

Comment: The code you gave on Bootply, it has the two things centered horizontally but not vertically. They're both stuck to the top. I want the top and bottom distances to be equal.

Comment: just click the device icons and you will see they're vertically aligned, I don't know why the Bootply preview isn't showing correctly, but in render view works as intended

Comment: With your code, the available space to fill has actually covered the whole height but my matter is still in the same position as before. Can't figure out why